# how to get value of next (Closest) td from html using vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a HTML file and I get a td from inner html  now I need to find closest td value from the td that I found in my html file please some one help me out of this

```
    For Each item In itemlist 'look at each item in the collection
                            If item.Innerhtml = "Controller" Then
                                MsgBox(item.innertext) 'this would msgbox your description
                                Exit For 'exit once found
                            End If
```

you can see in code I have get the specific td now I need to get the value of closet td, I can't do the same to find next td because next td does not contains any inner html or id its just contains value

Answer (score 1):

If i haven't misunderstood your question: 
You could use a simple "for" instead a "fore each" and, when you find the right td, get the next one incrementing the index by 1.
Example:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To itemlist.Count
  Dim item = itemlist.Item(i);
  If item.Innerhtml = "Controller" Then
    MsgBox(item.innertext) 
    Dim iNext = i++;
    if iNext <= itemList.Count Then 
       Dim closestItem = itemList.Item(iNext)
       'Do things
    End If
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Three notes: **1)** You've got to loop to `itemlist.Count - 1`, otherwise it'll go out of bounds since indexes start at zero. **2)** For the same reason you must also change your `If`-statement to: `If iNext < itemList.Count Then` **3)** `i++` is not valid VB.NET syntax. Use `i + 1` instead.

Comment: Thank you Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

```
   For Each item In itemlist 'look at each item in the collection
                            If item.Innerhtml = "Controller" Then
                                Controller = item.nextSibling.innertext.ToString.Trim 'this would save your description
                            End If
```

this is how I resolve the issue